# Pyspark could not find suitable TLS CA certificate after zipping the package

Tags: python, apache-spark, ssl, pyspark, python-requests

I have created a Pyspark application from this [pyspark-example-project](https://github.com/AlexIoannides/pyspark-example-project). In the example project, *dependencies.zip* is a dependency package which contains my actual code. I'm using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for posting metadata of the spark-submit job to https enabled endpoint.

I'm submitting the job as follows:
`spark-submit --master local[*] --py-files dependencies.zip job.py`

This results in

```sh
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, while running spark-submit,
File "/private/var/folders/_2/4jk9zwf11yx6h93v9nyv284r0000gn/T/spark-2604a272-4da7-45e9-98a4-02110c71f4db/userFiles-1b562995-6006-47a1-8d98-5102449063fa/dependencies.zip/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
  File "/private/var/folders/_2/4jk9zwf11yx6h93v9nyv284r0000gn/T/spark-2604a272-4da7-45e9-98a4-02110c71f4db/userFiles-1b562995-6006-47a1-8d98-5102449063fa/dependencies.zip/requests/adapters.py", line 226, in cert_verify
    "invalid path: {0}".format(cert_loc))
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /private/var/folders/_2/4jk9zwf11yx6h93v9nyv284r0000gn/T/spark-2604a272-4da7-45e9-98a4-02110c71f4db/userFiles-1b562995-6006-47a1-8d98-5102449063fa/dependencies.zip/certifi/cacert.pem
```

While `boto3` is working fine with dependencies in the zipped archived, *dependencies.zip/boto3*.

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried logging `certifi.where()`, it gives the same path mentioned in the log, i.e.

```
/private/var/folders/_2/4jk9zwf11yx6h93v9nyv284r0000gn/T/spark-2604a272-4da7-45e9-98a4-02110c71f4db/userFiles-1b562995-6006-47a1-8d98-5102449063fa/dependencies.zip/certifi/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `requests` will attempt to read the CA certificates as part of its SSL verification steps, expecting these certificates to be regular files. In your case, the certificates are zipped, as hinted by the call to `certifi.where()`.

Note that [requests#4371](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/4371) was made to tackle cases such as this one. By the time you wrote your post, this fix should have been in master so you were likely using an older version of `requests`.

A work-around is to specify the path to an unzipped certificate, whenever SSL verification is needed. With `boto3` you could apply a similar solution as `requests` has in place:

```py
import certifi
from requests.utils import extract_zipped_paths

cert_path = extract_zipped_paths(certifi.where())
ssm = boto3.client("ssm", verify=cert_path)
```